# Can AWS proxy be used to enable https for a http backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy

I have received an AWS EC2 instance running a web application, which is only available in http (insecure). Can I use AWS proxy such that the publicly accessible URL is https, and http happens only within AWS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application Load Balancer to hide http endpoint behind https

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Interesting, I hadn't considered that. However that would cost about $16 per month (plus traffic), pretty steep. Do you know a cheaper option?

Comment: @mitchus, I can provide some sort of crazy idea - use API gateway with HTTP Integration Request. It's a lot cheaper, but you need to have EIP for your EC2 instance (because public ip would change after ec2 instance restart)

Comment: I will look at that, because it seems that the Load Balancer idea does not work: configuration requires two subnets, but I have only one instance.

Comment: ELB needs multiple subnets only for redundancy. You can have 2 subnets and one ec2 instance. I did it for my first AWS project, so I can say - it's definitely works!